# C++ Visual Studio 2015 - Creating a DLL and Using it in Console Application

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015

All,

I am trying to do a very simple task that in C# is a simple routine, however I am currently trying to get familiar with C++ by creating a DLL and referencing it in a Win32 Console Application. I've honestly followed every step described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(v=vs.140).aspx in a lot of detail, however I still get an error as shown below:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MathFuncsDll, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  dllmain.cpp
1>  MathFuncsDll.cpp
1>     Creating library C:\Users\Dilmer\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DynamicLibrary\Debug\MathFuncsDll.lib and object C:\Users\Dilmer\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DynamicLibrary\Debug\MathFuncsDll.exp
1>  MathFuncsDll.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Dilmer\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DynamicLibrary\Debug\MathFuncsDll.dll
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyExecRefsDll, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>  stdafx.cpp
2>  MyExecRefsDll.cpp
2>  Generating Code...
2>MyExecRefsDll.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static double __cdecl MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Add(double,double)" (__imp_?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z) referenced in function _main
2>C:\Users\Dilmer\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DynamicLibrary\Debug\MyExecRefsDll.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Here's my DLL Project Called MathFuncsDll:**

MathFuncsDll.h

```
#ifdef MATHFUNCSDLL_EXPORTS
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace MathFuncs
{
    class MyMathFuncs
    {
    public:
        static MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Add(double a, double b);

        static MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Substract(double a, double b);

        static MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Multiply(double a, double b);

        static MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Divide(double a, double b);
    };
}
```

MathFuncsDll.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MathFuncsDll.h"
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

namespace MathFuncs 
{
    MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Add(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Substract(double a, double b) {
        return a - b;
    }

    MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Multiply(double a, double b) {
        return a * b;
    }

    MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Divide(double a, double b) {
        if (b == 0)
        {
            throw invalid_argument("b cannot be zero!");
        }
        return a / b;
    }
}
```

**Here's my console application MyExecRefsDll project:**

MyExecRefsDll.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MathFuncsDll.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a = 7.5;
    int b = 99;

    MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Add(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

I've also added ..\MathFuncsDll\ to Additional Include Directories. Let me know if you can think of some options, I haven't been able to get this to work and I don't think it should be as difficult as this is.

Comment: Set the dependency of the console project on the dll project.  Alternatively, add the lib of the dll project to the link of the console project.  Lots of ways to skin a cat: those are just two.

Comment: You didn't tell the project what library to use that contains those functions.  The "Additional Includes" directory is only used during the compilation step, not the link phase (which is where you are to set the library to use in your project settings).

Comment: It is just like the linker error says, you did **not** write a MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Add() function.  You wrote a MathFuncs::Add() function instead.  Hard to guess how you copied the [MSDN example code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx) wrong, details matter in C++ land.

Comment: MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Add(a, b); is the same as MyMathFuncs:Add(a, b); the MathFuncs is just the namespace so to me that shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Hans is right. Read the comment again. Replace `MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Add(double a, double b)` by `MATHFUNCSDLL_API double MyMathFuncs::Add(double a, double b)` in `MathFuncsDll.cpp`